# Position of 'for' preposition in sentence

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct and why?

> 1. Reports are important for her to know **for which** categories money are
>    spent and how to optimise it.
> 2. Reports are important for her to know **what** categories money are
>    spent **for** and how to optimise it.

Comment: The elephant in the room is that you do not spend money for categories. In point of fact, you don't spend it for anything. There's also tiny baby elephants running between the huge elephant's legs, and none of them has to do with what you are asking about. This is a great example of an X for Y question and as such I suggest you take it to chat, for which you have sufficient rep.

Comment: thanks! have 't ever knew about this chat. Event after years of stackexchange usage.

Comment: The comment by @RegDwigнt a little too prescriptive for me, since people have been spending money for stuff for at least a hundred years

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spend+money+for%22&rlz=1C9BKJA_enUS752US752&hl=en-US&tbm=bks&prmd=nsvi&ei=tn_wWt_dIczujwTYm4vQDQ&start=10&sa=N&biw=834&bih=1092&dpr=2

Answer (score -1):

Let me copy answer from chat here for future readers with same question:

You spend money/time/etc *on* something, not *for* something.
(for is possible for another meaning that you don't need to be concerned with now.)
Therefore, neither choice below is the optimal wording.

> **for** which categories money are spent
>
> what categories money are spent **for**

Change *for* for *on*, and both are correct, with the former being more formal.

> **on** which categories money is spent
>
> what categories money is spent **on**

Also, money *is* spent, not *are*.